# Displaying data from XML file using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following XML file containing letter and word definitions in this format A - B - C - D - etc…

```
<container>
    <data name="apple" definition="A sweet fruit. bla bla bla"/>
    <data name="bat" definition="bla bla bla"/>
    <data name="book" definition="bla bla bla"/>
    <data name="cat" definition="bla bla bla"/>
    <data name="cup" definition="bla bla bla"/>
</container>
```

If I click on `B` it should load *bat* and *book* in a box. If I click on *book* it should display related definition on the right area. How can I create this functionality using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your HTML is like this:

```
<div class="search" data-letter="a">A</div>
<div class="search" data-letter="b">B</div>
<div class="search" data-letter="c">C</div>
<div class="search" data-letter="d">D</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Then the javascript:

```
$(function(){

    var xml_data;

    // Load the XML
    $.get("your_xml_file.xml", function(data){

        xml_data = $(data);

        // On click of search buttons
        $(".search").bind("click", function(){

            // Clear the results div
            $("#results").html("");

            // Get the desired letter
            var letter = $(this).data("letter");

            // Loop through each result which has name attribute beginning with letter
            xml_data.find("data[name^='"+letter+"']").each(function(k, v){

                // Append definition to results
                $("#results").append($(this).attr("definition") + "<br/>");
            });

        });

    });

});
```

This should do what you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

If you are loading the XML from a string:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        ul ul, span {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var xml = '<container><data name="apple" definition="A sweet fruit. bla bla bla"/><data name="bat" definition="bla bla bla"/><data name="book" definition="bla bla bla"/><data name="cat" definition="bla bla bla"/><data name="cup" definition="bla bla bla"/></container>';
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
            var $xml = $(xmlDoc).find('container');
            var letters = new Object();

            // loop through all the definitions
            $xml.children().each(function(k, v) {
                var letter = $(v).attr('name').charAt(0);

                // only add letters not already added
                if (!letters[letter]) {
                    $('#definitions')
                        .append('<li><a href="#" id="' + letter + '">' + letter + '</a><ul></ul></li>');
                    letters[letter] = 'f';
                }

                // append definitions
                $('#definitions a#' + letter + ' + ul').append('<li><a href="#">' + $(v).attr('name') + '</a><span> - ' + $(v).attr('definition') + '</span></li>');
            });

            // bind click events on the letters to show/hide the words
            $('#definitions li > a').click(function() {
                $(this).next('ul').toggle();
                return false;
            });

            // bind click events on the words to show/hide the definitions
            $('#definitions ul li a').click(function() {
                $(this).next('span').toggle();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Defintions</h1>
    <ul id="definitions"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Or if you are loading via AJAX, replace the JavaScript with:

```
$(function() {
    var $xml;
    var letters = new Object();

    if ($xml == null) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'definitions.xml',
            dataType : 'xml',
            success : function (xml) {
                $xml = $(xml).find('container');
                console.log($xml);
                $xml.children().each(function(k, v) {
                    var letter = $(v).attr('name').charAt(0).toUpperCase();

                    // only add letters not already added
                    if (!letters[letter]) {
                        $('#definitions')
                            .append('<li><a href="#" id="' + letter + '">' + letter + '</a><ul></ul></li>');
                        letters[letter] = '.'; // store this key in the map (no actual value)
                    }

                    // append definitions
                    $('#definitions a#' + letter + ' + ul').append('<li><a href="#">' + $(v).attr('name') + '</a><span> - ' + $(v).attr('definition') + '</span></li>');
                });

                // bind click events on the letters to show/hide the words
                $('#definitions li > a').click(function() {
                    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
                    return false;
                });

                // bind click events on the words to show/hide the definitions
                $('#definitions ul li a').click(function() {
                    $(this).next('span').toggle();
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Please be aware that this may not be the best solution with a large XML file; the browser will have to transfer the entire file first, before rendering the page. So you may need to investigate an alternate solution, perhaps creating an `a-z` list on a page and then dynamically loading the words when a user clicks on a letter. Therefore only the relevant and necessary words & definitions are transferred on demand. You could also cache this to avoid duplicate requests for the same definitions.

Answer (score 1):

jquery is capable of consuming XML. You would like need to use the [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function to iterate through your XML and create your page structure from that.